# JQuery ui autocomplete send items list to a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

I've an autocomplete form that returns the values ​​in a HTML list and remove item on click :

```
...
//Print selected item
select: function(event, ui) {
    var message = ui.item.value;
    //Display item
    $('<li/>').text(message).prependTo("#result");
    $( "#result" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    //Clear autocomplete form
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).val('');
    //Deselect item
    $("#result").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.selected).remove();
        }
    });
}
...
```

The HTML form :

```
...
<form id="form" >
    <ol id="selectable" class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em">
        <li id="result" class="ui-widget-content" style="height: 200px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;"></li>
    </ol>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>
...
```

Now, how can I send the items list to a PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, it would be easy to use it's `$.ajax()` method (though I'd recommend learning how to implement that in raw JS, it's fairly easy).  Another option is to send the form's data through `$_POST` by changing the form tag to:

```
<form id="form" action="path/to/php" method="post">
```